# How to properly handle input for the DS4 controller left joystick and use it to move a symbol in different directions

Tags: c

I have a c program. And I need to add all these features: Develop an input method so that a user can select one of the displayed words using the DualShock 4.indicate the word currently selected by placing a character next to it using the draw char function. Begin with an empty sentence at the bottom of the screen. The TRIANGLE button will append a space to the current sentence followed by
the selected word. The X button will remove the last item (a word, punctuation, or letter) added. You need to be able to use the remove feature multiple times in a row. Think of it as an “undo” button in software you use on a daily basis. The X button also needs to remove everything in the last command (including spaces). The SQUARE button will append the word but without adding a space.
All of this program is reading words from a "wordslist.txt" file.
Words from the file that is being read:
the
of
to
and
a
in
is
it
you
that
he
was
for
she
on
are
with
I
as
they
class
be
am
one
have
said
want
air
cat
dog
way
up
about
many
like
so
these
her
long
thing
see
him
two
day
people
.
,
?
!
animal
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z

Here is my C program:

```
// Lab 9 DS4Talker Skeleton Code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>


#define MAXWORDS 100
#define WORDLEN 11
#define DEBUG 1   // set to 0 to disable debug output
#define UP 0
#define DOWN 1
#define LEFT 2
#define RIGHT 3

// reads words from the file
// into wl and trims the whitespace off of the end of each word
// DO NOT MODIFY THIS Prototype
int readWords(char* wl[MAXWORDS], char* filename); 

//modifies s to trim white space off the right side
// DO NOT MODIFY THIS Prototype
void trimws(char* s) ;
void draw_character(int x, int y, char use);
void clear_words(char *arr, int len);
void back_space(char arr[80]);
void und_char(char arr[80], int num);



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* wordlist[MAXWORDS];
    int wordCount;
    int i, j;
    //int t, triButton, squButton, cirButton, xButton, left_jx, left_jy, right_jx, right_jy; 
    wordCount = readWords(wordlist, argv[1]);
    initscr();
    //int x = 0;
    int rows = 0; 
    int cols = 0; 
    char avatar = '<';
    char space = ' ';


    if (DEBUG) {
        printf("Read %d words from %s \n", wordCount, argv[1]);
        
        /*for (int i = 0; i < (wordCount/5) + 1; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            
                if (x < wordCount) {
                    mvprintw(i,j*15, "%15s", wordlist[x]);
                    x++;
                }
                
            }
            
             
        } */

        //Prints the words on the screen
        for (i = 0; i< wordCount; i++) {
            printf("%s,", wordlist[i]);

        }
        printf("\n");
        }

        //down, up, left, right
        int dir[6];
        
        //down, up, left, right, blah1, blah2
        int dir1[6];
        int t, last_t, x, y, track, cx, cy, cd, moving, first, loc, pressed;
        cy = 0;
        cx = 0;
        char sentence[80];
        clear_words(sentence, 80);
        strcpy(sentence, "");
        char currentWord[WORDLEN];
        char tmp[15]; 
        clear_words(tmp, 15);
        clear_words(currentWord, 11);
        initscr();
        refresh();
        first = TRUE; 
        pressed = FALSE; 
        int ladded; 
        int swap = 1; 
        char changes[100][80];
        int rev = 0;

        do {

        scanf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", &t, &dir[0], &dir[1], &dir[2], &dir[3], &dir[4], &dir[5], &dir1[0], &dir1[1], &dir1[2], &dir1[3], &dir1[4], &dir1[5]);

        if (first == TRUE) {
            last_t = t; 
            first = FALSE;
        }

        if(t - last_t >= 300) {
            moving = TRUE; 
            if (swap == 1) {
                pressed = FALSE; 
                swap = 0; 
            }

            else if (swap == 0) {
                swap = 1;
            }
            last_t = t; 
        }

        else { 
            moving = FALSE; 
        }

        
    



    mvprintw(cy, cx, "%c", avatar);
    

    clear_words(currentWord, 11);

    loc = cx/15 + cy*5;
    //currentWord = wordlist[loc];
    strcpy(currentWord, wordlist[loc]);
    mvprintw(17, 0, "%s", currentWord); 
        

      // Handle TRIANGLE button (append space and word)
    if (dir[2] > 0) {
        strcat(sentence, " ");
        strcat(sentence, currentWord);
        pressed = TRUE;
    }

    // Handle X button (remove last item or command)
    else if (dir[0] > 0) {
        back_space(sentence);
        pressed = TRUE;
    }

    // Handle SQUARE button (append word without space)
    else if (dir[3] > 0) {
        strcat(sentence, currentWord);
        pressed = TRUE;
    }


if (t % 35 < 5) {
    if (dir1[0] > 0) { // Up
        if (cy > 0) {
            cy--;
        }
    } else if (dir1[1] > 0) { // Down
        if (cy < 4) {  // Assuming 5 rows of words
            cy++;
        }
    } else if (dir1[2] > 0) { // Left
        if (cx > 0) {
            cx -= 15;
        }
    } else if (dir1[3] > 0) { // Right
        if (cx < (5 - 1) * 15) {  // Assuming 5 columns with 15 characters each
            cx += 15;
        }
    }
}
     

    // Clear the screen before redrawing
    clear();


    // Print the words on the screen
    y = 0;
    x = 0;
    track = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        mvprintw(y, x, "%s", wordlist[i]);
        x += 15;
        track++;
        if (track == 5) {
            mvprintw(y, x, "\n");
            y++;
            x = 0;
            track = 0;
        }
    }

    // Draw the character at its new position
    draw_character(cx, cy, '<');

    // Draw the character at the right side of the selected word
    draw_character(cx + 1, cy, '<');

    // Refresh the screen
    refresh();

    


    

    if (pressed == FALSE) {
        if (dir[1] > 0) {
             strcat(sentence, " ");
                strcat(sentence, currentWord);
                pressed = TRUE;

            //mvprintw(17, 0, "%s", tmp); 

            pressed = TRUE; 
        }

        else if (dir[0]) {
            back_space(sentence);
                pressed = TRUE;
        }

        else if (dir[2]) {
            strcat(sentence, currentWord);
                pressed = TRUE;
        }
    }
    


    clear_words(sentence, 80); 
    strcpy(sentence, ""); 
    for ( int k = 0; k <= rev; k++) {
        strcat(sentence, changes[k]);

    }
    
    mvprintw(16, 0, "%s", sentence); 
    refresh();


        } while (1);

        refresh(); 
        endwin(); 
        return 0; 
}

    
 










int readWords(char* wl[MAXWORDS], char* filename) {
    
    FILE* read = fopen("wordslist.txt", "r"); 
    int word = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXWORDS && !feof(read); i++) {
        char newWord[WORDLEN]; 
        fscanf(read, "%s", newWord);
        trimws(newWord);
        wl[i] = (char*) malloc(strlen(newWord) + 1);
        strcpy(wl[i], newWord); 
        word++; 
    }
        
    return word; 
}


void trimws(char* s) {

    for (int i = 0; i < WORDLEN; i++) {

        if (s[i] == ' ') {
            
            s[i] = '\0'; 

        }

    }

}

void draw_character(int x, int y, char use) {
    mvaddch(y,x,use);    
    refresh();
}


void clear_words(char *arr, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = 0; 
    }

    arr[0] = '\0';
}


void back_space(char arr[80]) {
     size_t pos = strlen(arr);
    int i = (int)pos - 1;

    // Handle removing multiple characters in a row
    while (i >= 0 && arr[i] == ' ') {
        i--;
    }

    // Remove the last item (word, punctuation, or letter)
    while (i >= 0 && arr[i] != ' ') {
        arr[i] = '\0';
        i--;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 80; j++) {
        arr[j] = 0;
    }
}

void und_char(char arr[80], int num) {
    size_t pos = strlen(arr);
    int start = (int)pos;
    
    for (int i = start; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((start - i) == num) {
            arr[i] = '\0'; 
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = i  + 1; i < 80; i++) {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }

}
```

I tried doing the above with the code, but the character ends up drawing on the letter and when I move it down, it moves down with the right joystick and not the left. It should move up down left and right with the left joystick however that doesn't work. Nothing works and I just need a solution very quick.

Here is the sample output of the program:
the <          of             to             and            a
in             is             it             you            that
he             was            for            she            on
are            with           I              as             they
class          be             am             one            have
said           want           air            cat            dog
way            up             about          many           like
so             these          her            long           thing
see            him            two            day            people
.              ,              ?              !              animal
a              b              c              d              e
f              g              h              i              j
k              l              m              n              o
p              q              r              s              t
u              v              w              x              y
z              z

As you can see, the program must organize them into these columns. And the user must be able to move that symbol up and down left and right and choose the right word with those functionalities and features that I provided.